# How to save value of a string even after the activity/app is destroyed?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, onpause, ondestroy, android-sharedpreferences

I have 2 `int` in my navigation drawer, the value of whom changes upon clicking different button on different locations in the app.

I got the code to successfully  increment and update them, but the problem is that they got reset when I open the app after closing or exiting it.

How can I make them stay there after getting updated?

If you want any code from my app, then please tell me.

Sorry for bad formatting of the question, but I have no idea how to do this and hence I haven't posted any code.

Answer (score 1):

You must save the info in a persistent storage.

You can use `SharedPreferences`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("aName", MODE_PRIVATE);
 //save the value   
        prefs.edit()
                .putInt("nameOfTheValue", theValue).apply();        
        // get the data       
        prefs.getInt("nameOfTheValue", aDefaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save them as [User SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in onDestroy method.

```
  public void onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy();
     SharedPreferences settings;
     settings = getSharedPreferences("TWO_INT_SAVING", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     //set the sharedpref
      Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt("FIRST_INT", firstIntValue);
      editor.putInt("SECOND_INT", secondIntValue);
      editor.commit();
    }
```

And then you can get them back wen needed:

```
  SharedPreferences settings;
  settings = getSharedPreferences("TWO_INT_SAVING", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  //get the sharepref
  int firstInt = settings.getInt("FIRST_INT", 0);
  int secondInt = settings.getInt("SECOND_INT", 0);
```